# Access non Istio resource

Tags: kubernetes, istio

My current version of istio is 0.2.12.
I have a deployment that is deployed with istio kube-inject and tries to connect to a service/deployment inside of the kubernetes cluster that not uses Istio, how is it possible to allow access from the istio using deployment to the not istio using deployment.
In this case is the istio baked deployment a Spring boot application and the other is an ephemeral MySQL server.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to access all the kubernetes services (Istio-injected and the regular Kubernetes ones) from Istio-injected pods.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I found out that this is a problem of istio installed with mutual tls auth enabled.

Comment: Oh, I see. There is work in progress in Istio to mark on which services to enable/disable mutual TLS.

Answer (score 0):

This now possible, please see the 
"Can I enable Istio Auth with some services while disable others in the same cluster?"

question in the security section of the faq: https://istio.io/help/faq.html